# Цикл JS ошибка Cannot read property '1' of null

Tags: javascript

Вот цикл

```
var html = '          <achiev id="1">9</achiev>

            <achiev id="2">4</achiev>

            <achiev id="3">9</achiev>

            <achiev id="4">12</achiev>

            <achiev id="5">3</achiev>
            <achiev>И так далеееее</achiev>';

var achiev_id =506;
var achiev =0;
var i = 1;
while (i < achiev_id) {
var re = '/<achiev id="'+i+'">(.*?)<\/achiev>/i';
var pars = html.match(re);
var achiev_count = pars[1];
achiev = achiev + achiev_count;
i++;
}
```

Пишет ошибку (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null) на этой строке

```
var achiev_count = pars[1];
```

Что я сделал не так?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/fV2EW/

Answer (score 1):

В JS регекспы пишутся без кавычек, прямо в слешах. Но в данном случае придется использовать полную запись:

`var re = new RegExp('<achiev id="'+i+'">(.*?)<\/achiev>', 'i');`

Comment: Увы ошибка осталась

Comment: Теперь она возникает когда ничего не находит

Comment: Так там же вроде всё есть